# Setting two pgfplots-styles to be used with \addplot

Tags: pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+ [only marks,
nodes near coords,
point meta=explicit symbolic,
every node near coord/.style={
anchor=north east,
yshift=-1pt,
xshift=2pt}] table [x index=0,y index=1,meta index=1] {
0 0 -3 
1 1 -2
2 2 -1
};

\addplot+ [only marks,
nodes near coords,
point meta=explicit symbolic,
every node near coord/.style={
anchor=south east,
xshift=2pt,
yshift=1pt}] table [x index=0,y index=1,meta index=2] {
0 0 -3 
1 1 -2
2 2 -1
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: Result]

I have quite a few plots of this type with values written above left and below left of the coordinates.

I would like to put the options to `\addplot+` in a style of some sort and simplify the code to something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{southwestpoint/.style={only marks,
nodes near coords,
point meta=explicit symbolic,
every node near coord/.style={
anchor=north east,
yshift=-1pt,
xshift=2pt}}}

\pgfplotsset{northwestpoint/.style={only marks,
nodes near coords,
point meta=explicit symbolic,
every node near coord/.style={
anchor=south east,
xshift=2pt,
yshift=1pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+ [southwestpoint] table [x index=0,y index=1,meta index=1] {
0 0 -3 
1 1 -2
2 2 -1
};

\addplot+ [northwestpoint] table [x index=0,y index=1,meta index=2] {
0 0 -3 
1 1 -2
2 2 -1
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But this gives an error:

> Runaway argument?
>   {northwestpoint.style={only marks, nodes near coords, point meta=exp\ETC.
>   ! File ended while scanning use of \pgfkeys@@qset.
>    
>                   \par

I'm guessing there is an error with the expansion but I'm not really an expert in TeX programming so I haven't been able to solve it. I also [tried using with `\def\northwestpoint{...}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36144/49901) but got other errors.

How can I create an addplot-style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just missing one closing brace in the definition of `northwestpoint`. Note that for `southwestpoint` you have three closing braces at the end of the `\pgfplotsset`, but in `northwestpoint` there are two.

Here's a slightly different version, which makes use of the fact that you can nest styles, and also prints the numbers in math mode, so you get proper minus signs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
point/.style={
  only marks,
  nodes near coords={$\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta$},
  point meta=explicit symbolic,
},
southwestpoint/.style={
  point,
  every node near coord/.style={
    anchor=north east,
    yshift=-1pt,
    xshift=2pt}
},
northwestpoint/.style={
  point,
  every node near coord/.style={
    anchor=south east,
    xshift=2pt,
    yshift=1pt}
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+ [southwestpoint] table [x index=0,y index=1,meta index=1] {
0 0 -3 
1 1 -2
2 2 -1
};

\addplot+ [northwestpoint] table [x index=0,y index=1,meta index=2] {
0 0 -3 
1 1 -2
2 2 -1
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're right.. I've been trying for hours, probably with different syntax errors, this shows how valuable a proper MWE can be.. Thanks for your help and for the additional suggestions for improving the code!!