# Spaces and commata in StringOptions (as possible in hyperref)

Tags: kvoptions

I want to write a little documentclass which can be used with options, e. g.

```
\documentclass[title=a]{xyz}
```

In order to do this, I wrote in the `xyz.cls`

```
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions{
  family=abc,
  prefix=abc@
}
\DeclareStringOption{title}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*
```

However, it is not possible to write something like

```
\documentclass[title={Riemann surfaces, projective curves and function fields}]{xyz}
```

In this situation, the macro `\abc@title` has the value `Riemannsurfaces` (i. e. without spaces and just the part before the first comma). I've already tried the `patch`-option for the `kvoptions`-package.

Is there a way to implement this properly (it is possible in the `hyperref`-package, e. g. `\usepackage[pdftitle={Riemann surfaces, ...}]{hyperref}`)?

Comment: Braces are always problematic when fed as global options (that is, to `\documentclass`). Can you make a small MWE, please?

Comment: Not to mention spaces, which are zapped when the global options are processed for being stored in the variable for later handing to the loaded packages.

Comment: I solved the problem by using `xkeyval` and `xkvltxp` instead of `kvoptions`.

Comment: You should write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using spaces in class options is basically not supported by the latex2e engine (see [github issue](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/85)). There are some workarounds for that problem but these work not for every class (and therefore it usually won't work for your own class as you usually would write a class which based on another class). General speaking you should avoid spaces in class options (at least for latex2e, maybe there are better solutions for Latex3). However if you insist on it, in the following are given three solutions which at least work with some classes.

**Solution 1: Using `pgfopts`**

.tex file:

```
\documentclass[title={with space and, comma}]{xyz}
\begin{document}
    the Title is \title
\end{document}
```

xyz.cls file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{xyz}[2020/07/14]
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}

\LoadClass{article}

\pgfkeys{
    /xyz/.cd,
    title/.store in=\xyz@title
}

\ProcessPgfOptions{/xyz}

\renewcommand{\title}{\xyz@title}
```

This doesn't work with [KOMAscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461020/komascript-gives-error-when-using-parenthesis-within-options) (in the linked thread is shown a workaround for it but I didn't try it).

**Solution 2: Using `xkeyval`**

See [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468660/string-parameter-passed-to-a-class-vanish-the-spaces-between-words) for a minimum working example. As shown in the linked thread you need in opposite to the `hyperref` package two instead of one curly brackets before and after the value. This will also not work with KOMAScript (for the same reason as for Solution 1).

**Solution 3: Loading `kvoptions-patch` before \documentclass in the .tex file**

I don't know how to get the `kvoptions-patch` working in the `.cls` file but for some reason it is working with out problem when it is loaded before the `\documentclass` command inside the `.tex` file.

.tex file:

```latex
\RequirePackage{kvoptions-patch}
\documentclass[title=with space]{xyz}
\begin{document}
    the Title is: \printTitle
\end{document}
```

xyz.cls file:

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{xyz}[2020/07/14]
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\LoadClass{article}

\DeclareStringOption[]{title}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions* 

\newcommand{\printTitle}{\xyz@title}
```

In addition to the obvious disadvantage that it is confusing for class users that they need to load the `kvoptions` package before the `\documentclass` another drawback of this method is that you can't use commas inside values (e.g in the title in the above example). However this solution also works with KOMAScript.