# KOMAscript gives error when using parenthesis within options

Tags: koma-script, class-options

Coming up from my previous question [How to use equal sign inside class option with pgfopts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461011/how-to-use-equal-sign-inside-class-option-with-pgfopts) I switched the base class from `article` to `scrartcl` and ran into a compile error.

> l.451 \FamilyProcessOptions{KOMA}
>                                 \relax
>
> Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
>   Missing character: There is no , in font nullfont!
>   ! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
>   > @removeelement #1#2#3->\def \reserved@a ##1,#1,##
>   2\reserved@a {##1,##2\rese...
>   l.451 \FamilyProcessOptions{KOMA}

Here is the example I've used

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.cls}
    \ProvidesClass{\jobname}[2018-11-20 v1.0 SE Test package]
    \RequirePackage{pgfopts}
    \pgfkeys{
        testproj/.cd,
        mystuff/.store in = \myValue,
        mystuff = {} % <-- Set default to empty
    }
    \ProcessPgfOptions{/testproj}
    \LoadClass[\myValue]{scrartcl} % article is working
    \endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[mystuff={hello=SE,test=1}]{\jobname}
%\pgfkeys{/testproj/mystuff = {hello=SE}} % <-- working as aspected
\begin{document}
    myValue: \myValue
\end{document}
```

Is this a bug in KOMAScript or do I miss something else? The goal is using `scrreprt` and `scrbook`.

Comment: basically you can not use `{}` in `\documentclass` options. As it happens I'm currently looking at whether it is possible to extend latex here (the easy part) in a way that it is compatible with all existing packages (the hard part)

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/85

Comment: Well, I see it is not that easy as expected. But why was it working using `article`?

Comment: the KOMA classes have their own key-val handler (they have to process keys like fontsize=12pt), and this is interfering.

Comment: you might have got lucky but `\@removeelement ` is in the latex format and if the element you try to remove (typically an option from the unused option list) has a brace group it fails rather spectacularly, it just was not written with key=value processing in mind at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might possibly be safe but it's a very delicate area of latex2e code

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.cls}
    \ProvidesClass{\jobname}[2018-11-20 v1.0 SE Test package]
    \RequirePackage{pgfopts}
    \pgfkeys{
        testproj/.cd,
        mystuff/.store in = \myValue,
        mystuff = {} % <-- Set default to empty
    }
\let\zzz \@expandtwoargs
\def\@expandtwoargs#1#2#3{%
  \edef\tmp@zz{\noexpand\zzz\noexpand#1{\noexpand\detokenize{#2}}{\noexpand\detokenize{#3}}}%
   \tmp@zz}
    \ProcessPgfOptions{/testproj}
    \LoadClass[\myValue]{scrartcl} % article is working
    \let\@expandtwoargs\zzz 
    \endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[mystuff={hello=SE,test=1}]{\jobname}
%\pgfkeys{/testproj/mystuff = {hello=SE}} % <-- working as aspected
\begin{document}
    myValue: \myValue
\end{document}
```

it detokenizes the arguments (making `{}` safe) before using `\in@` but this may have unexpected consequences elsewhere....

Comment: This seems to work. As far as I could test it there is no unexpected consequence. But probably it is better to do some rework so that I won't need that magic.