# Unable to retain Whitespace in xkeyval

Tags: hyperref, white-space, xkeyval

I am using [the xkeyval package](https://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval?lang=en) to set a key "name". This value is then used in [the hyperref package](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref?lang=en). Please see the sample code below:

**File: mysuperclass.cls**

```
\ProvidesClass{mysuperclass}
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{xkeyval}%

\def\docauthorname{A. U. Thor}%
\def\docname{\jobname.tex}%
\def\docdate{\today}%

\define@key{mysuperclass.cls}{docdate}[\today]{%
  \def\docdate{#1}%
}

\define@key{mysuperclass.cls}{author}[A. U. Thor]{%
  \def\docauthorname{#1}%
}
\define@key{mysuperclass.cls}{docname}[]{%
  \def\docname{#1}%
}

\ExecuteOptionsX{author,docdate}
\ProcessOptionsX%

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\lhead[\docauthorname]{{\docauthorname}}%
\chead[\docdate]{\docdate}%
\rhead[]{\docname}%
\pagestyle{fancy}%
}

\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
  pdfauthor={{\docauthorname}}%
}%
\endinput
```

**File: main.tex**

```
\documentclass[docdate=1/1/2016,author=My Full Name with Spaces,docname=yelostfile]{mysuperclass}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

Please note that the above code is taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250163/49520). Below is a screenshot of the generated PDF:
[image]

Please see below the PDF properties, pay attention to the author name:
[image]

I found a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468664/49520) and followed it. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem working as expected.

**My question is how to retain whitespaces in xkeyval?**

### Workaround

The [actual answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604717/49520) given by [@Skillmon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050/) which requires TexLive 2021-06-01 and uses [the expkv-opt package](https://ctan.org/pkg/expkv-opt?lang=en). [@Skillmon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050/), kindly suggested a workaround to avoid such dependencies. I am posting the complete code below for reference:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mysuperclass.cls}
\ProvidesClass{mysuperclass}
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

\define@key{mysuperclass.cls}{docdate}[\today]{
  \def\docdate{#1}
}

\define@key{mysuperclass.cls}{author}[A. U. Thor]{
  \def\docauthorname{#1}
}

\define@key{mysuperclass.cls}{docname}[My Document]{
  \def\docname{#1}
}

\ExecuteOptionsX{author,docdate,docname}
\ProcessOptionsX

\newcommand\setauthor[1]{
  \setkeys{mysuperclass.cls}{author=#1}
}

\newcommand\setdocdate[1]{
  \setkeys{mysuperclass.cls}{docdate=#1}
}

\newcommand\setdocname[1]{
  \setkeys{mysuperclass.cls}{docname=#1}
}

\AtEndPreamble{
  \hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={{\docauthorname}}
  }
  \AtBeginDocument{
    \lhead[\docauthorname]{{\docauthorname}}
    \chead[\docdate]{\docdate}
    \rhead[]{\docname}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
  }
}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{mysuperclass}
\setauthor{My Full Name with Spaces}
\setdocdate{1/1/2016}
\setdocname{yelostfile}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: the latex code to handle document options is *very* eager to remove spaces. with a current latex you could try to use the raw options list instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like [@UlrikeFischer said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604711/unable-to-retain-whitespace-in-xkeyval#comment1516485_604711), LaTeX's original class/package option parsing was eagerly removing spaces. In recent versions there is a raw option list for which the spaces aren't zapped, but most packages don't yet support parsing this list.

To my knowledge the only package parsing the raw options currently is `expkv-opt` (*disclaimer:* I'm the author of that).

The following uses `expkv-opt` to parse the option list given to `mysuperclass.cls` directly (it doesn't look at the class options if it was loaded via `\LoadClass`, for this you'd have to also add `\ekvoProcessGlobalOptions`). To define the keys for `expkv-opt` you could either use the low-level interface provided by `expkv`, or use `expkv-def` to define keys using a key=value interface with a few predefined key types. This answer does the latter.

```
\begin{filecontents}{mysuperclass.cls}
\ProvidesClass{mysuperclass}
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{expkv-def,expkv-opt}

\ekvdefinekeys{mysuperclass.cls}
  {
     store   docdate = \docdate
    ,default docdate = \today
    ,initial docdate = \today
    ,store   author  = \docauthorname
    ,default author  = A. U. Thor
    ,initial author  = A. U. Thor
    ,store   docname = \docname
    ,default docname = {}
    ,initial docname = \jobname.tex
  }

\ekvoProcessLocalOptions{mysuperclass.cls}

\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\lhead[\docauthorname]{{\docauthorname}}%
\chead[\docdate]{\docdate}%
\rhead[]{\docname}%
\pagestyle{fancy}%
}

\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
  pdfauthor={{\docauthorname}}%
}%
\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[docdate=1/1/2016,author=My Full Name with Spaces,docname=yelostfile]{mysuperclass}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I really ought to fix at least hyperref and kvoptions to do use the raw lists

Comment: @DavidCarlisle additionally we should nag Joseph to also fix `pgfopts` and `l3keys2e`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That reminds me of another, similar issue I never got around to asking about in here: If a package `\usepackage[...]` key value is set to be a command name, it seems that this command is fully expanded for some reason. For instance, this is the case if you run `\usepackage[keyval parser=\ekvparse]{semantex}`. Is this intentional, and can it be turned off?

Comment: @Gaussler it is related to the same issue. the argument handling is designed for `a4paper,12pt` not for keyval, it is fully expanded and all spaces are removed. The new raw option list handling allows modified option hanlers to access the original argument and use keyval processing without pre-expansion. But whichever package you are using to parse that argument needs to be updated to use the raw option lists.

Comment: @Gaussler even if you use a key=value solution that accesses the raw option list, this will not work currently.

Comment: @Skillmon: Thank you very much for kindly providing and explaining the answer. Unfortunately, I did not have the `expkv` package. I am using TeX Live 2020. I downloaded `dtx` files one by one and used `pdftex`. But I am still can't see spaces. Something wrong with the `dtx` conversion? Can you please have a look at my project file in [shared Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/a7aze0s9n8t684w/AADUEEd4NHZPMs2pamov4qbDa?dl=0)?

Comment: @RaviJoshi the required LaTeX code is from 2021-06-01, if `expkv-opt` finds that this isn't available it turns to compatibility mode and parses the zapped list like the other packages. Consider updating to TeX Live 2021 for this feature. If that's not possible use another interface (instead of package options create a setup macro that is called after the package is loaded, and delay the evaluation of the keys until the end of the preamble by using `\AtEndPreamble` provided by the `etoolbox` package).

Comment: @Skillmon: Thank you again. Using `\AtEndPreamble{\hypersetup{pdfauthor={{\docauthorname}}}}` it is easy to get `\docauthorname` but I could not understand, how to _create a setup macro that is called after the package is loaded_ I tried using `\define@key{mysuperclass.cls}` from `\RequirePackage{xkeyval}` but it does not seem working. [I am sharing my project in Dropbox. Can you please have a look?](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nbtm2131n9pskqm/AACah1ADii1gWr-rogZAuq6qa?dl=0) Thank you so much.

Comment: @RaviJoshi I won't look at your project, sorry. What I meant was do something like: `\newcommand\mysetup[1]{\setkeys{mysuperclass.cls}{#1}}` and tell the users to use that inside their preamble after the package/class was loaded instead of package/class options.

Comment: @Skillmon: Thank you very much. I added the suggested workaround in the question above and accepted the answer. Thanks again.